# Delete (a,b) from a python list of tuples if (b,a) exists

Tags: python, list

From a python list of tuples (which is essentially a cartesian product of a list with itself) I want to delete (a,b) if (b,a) is in the list.Only one of (a,b) or (b,a) must be retained. So a list

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
```

must reduce to

```
[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]
```

(Although deleting `(1,2)` and retaining `(2,1)` is fine)

I tried doing this but I am not sure about deleting from a list while iterating over it. This doesn't work. (Gives me `[(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 3)]`)

```
[pairs.remove((a,b)) for (a,b) in pairs if ((b,a) in pairs)]
```

Comment: Never mutate the list you're iterating on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why delete the incorrect ones from the list?

Use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate the correct ones instead.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations((1, 2, 3), 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Not exactly what I asked for but I exactly what I need.Must always remember to look into itertools.

Comment: @atlantis: This seems like a case of XY problem (:

Comment: There is literally nothing `itertools` can't do. I'm pretty sure  world hunger can be solved with an `itertools` one-liner.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> [el for el in pairs if el[0] < el[1]]
[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pairs = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)] 
new_pairs = []

for a, b in pairs:
    if (a, b) in new_pairs or (b, a) in new_pairs:
        pass
    else:
        new_pairs +=  [(a,b)]

new_pairs = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but probably because this doesn't eliminate tuples where both values are the same. fraxel's answer is also simpler, and you should just use `append` instead of `+=`.